# encodeBegin vs encodeEnd in JSF and which one should be preferred

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using the `javax.faces.render.Renderer` class to render my custom components. I override either `encodeBegin` or `encodeEnd` to achieve my desired output.

I would like to know when should I use either of these methods? Is there any guideline on when should `encodeBegin` and `encodeEnd` be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the component tree hierarchy. Key is, do you expect children? How do you want the encoded output to look like when there are children?

Usually, you use `encodeBegin()` if you want to encode output before children are encoded. E.g. a start tag like HTML `<div>`. Usually, you use `encodeEnd()` if you want to encode output after children are encoded. E.g. an end tag like HTML `</div>`. Or perhaps an additional `<script>` which should work on the before-generated `<div>`.

Comment: **encode output before/after children are encoded?** Does this mean generating HTML like `<div><span>span text</span>div text</div>`? But this can be generated even in a single method of `encodeBegin` or `encodeEnd`. Let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: With children I mean, `<your:component><other:childA/><other:childB/></your:component>`. Does it make sense now? You shouldn't care about actual encoding of children. They do all by themselves. But with `encodeBegin()`  you control the output before the children are encoded and with `encodeEnd()` the output thereafter.

Comment: Got it! :) Thanks for bearing with. I am kind off new to this JSF stuff.